#  ajax call from view to controller in Play framework

Tags: model-view-controller, jquery, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am newbie to MVC and Play framework (Java). Instead of using Groovy for dynamic HTML, I made our own page with static HTML, I mean we haven't any Groovy expressions. Here, I have a controller "Customer", generates JSON object which has to be sent to an ajax call in view. I tried with render() method, seems I haven't used correctly. can you give me some idea to forward from here. thanks.

```
public static void customer(){
    WordAPI objWordAPI=new WordAPI();
    List<WordInfo> listObjWord= objWordAPI.MakeAPIObject(nSurveyId);
    JSONSerializer modelSerializer=new JSONSerializer().exclude("NSpontanity","NWordRepresentativity","NWordValue","NWordFrequency","class").rootName("Words");
    render("Application/wordcloud.html",modelSerializer.serialize(listObjWord));
  }
```

and ajax call in view "wordcloud.html"

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/customer",
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
             }
        })
```

Comment: If you have a controller called Customer with a method called customer then the url should be /customer/customer. If you would like to use the url /customer then you would have to explicity define it in the conf/routes file

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
public static void customer(){
    WordAPI objWordAPI=new WordAPI();
    List<WordInfo> listObjWord= objWordAPI.MakeAPIObject(nSurveyId);
    JSONSerializer modelSerializer=new JSONSerializer().exclude("NSpontanity","NWordRepresentativity","NWordValue","NWordFrequency","class").rootName("Words");
    renderJSON(modelSerializer.serialize(listObjWord));
  }
```

I've never used rootName before, I usually just do something more like this:

```
public static void refreshNotifications()
    {
        JSONSerializer notifySerializer = new JSONSerializer().include("message","notifyId","class").exclude("*");
        List<Notification> notificationList = user.getNotifications();
        renderJSON(notifySerializer.serialize(notificationList));
    }
```

Side Note: With refreshNotifications I have a Security method I run before which verifies and populates the user object.